# How do I group by all non-null values and do not group null values

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql

I have a list of items in a table, I'm grouping on the name to get the sum. Some of these items have the name NULL, which I do not wish to group together.

Comment: apply the condition in the query: where Name is not NULL

Comment: Do you mean you want to exclude the NULL records from the result, or you want to display them individually (i.e., not grouped)?

Comment: @joe I wish to display them individually aka not grouped but only the null ones

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
SELECT itemname, SUM(whatever)
FROM tab
WHERE itemname IS NOT NULL
GROUP BY itemname

UNION ALL

SELECT itemname, whatever
FROM tab
WHERE itemname IS NULL
```

Comment: Last line should be `IS NULL`